# Easiest way to install the Ubuntu Mysql Security Patch

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, patch, vulnerabilities

I am looking for a quick and easy way to install the security fix for CVE-2012-2122 on my Ubuntu boxes.  I don't want to risk installing any of the other updates and I just want to install the critical security updates.  When I built my boxes out I set them to install sec updates automatically but I want to make sure I have this vuln patched given the extreme nature of it.